# html/PHP form not submitting after being generated with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a table full of forms that work normally, but after being filtered by a drop down using AJAX, the submit buttons aren't working anymore.

This is the table generated by AJAX

```
<table class="striped" style='padding-top:20px;'>
        <tr class="header"  style='border: solid 2px black; background-color: #FFF500; text-align:center; color: black;'>
            //All the tds
        </tr>
        <?php
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
               echo "<tr ><form action=someURL.php method=post>";

                           //all the data generated inside

               echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value=Submit></td>";


               echo "</form></tr>";
           }

        ?>
    </table>
```

This is the dropdown that calls makes the AJAX call the form

```
<select id="selectStuff" name="selectStuff" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"  style="font-size: 15px; background-color: white; width: auto;">
        <option value="">Select Something</option>
        <?php

        $query="SELECT iddivisiones,nombre FROM divisiones";
                        $db=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        while($d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)){

                         echo "<option value='".$d['iddivisiones']."'>".$d['nombre']."</option>";
                        }
        ?>  

    </select>
```

and here's the script with the AJAX

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectStuff').on('change',function(){
        var selectedId=$(this).val();
        if(selectedId){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'categoria-resultados.php',
                data:'seleccion='+selectedId,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#tables').html(html);
                }
            });
        }else{
             $('#tables').html('<option value="">failed</option>')
        }});    });
```

And the div where the forms table is supposed to appear

```
<div class="tables" id="tables"> </div>
```

Comment: use `<form action='someURL.php'  method='post'>` . `' '` are missing in your `form` header

Comment: Why are you putting `<option>` tags directly in a `<div>`? What filtering are you talking about?

Comment: Side note, AJAX, not AYAX. `$.ajax`

Comment: How are the form(s) submitted? If it is using AJAX you'll need to include that code too.

Comment: @Taplar, now the table doesn't even appear.

Comment: It's really hard to tell with the way you've presented the markup how they relate to each other, if at all.

Comment: @FunkDoc they are submited by pressing the submit button. the  echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value=Submit></td>"; one. the button itself is withing the table the ajax brings. does that counts?

Comment: you are generating invalid HTML. You cannot span tags like you are - ie: tr > form > td. You ought to have tr > td > form